# What are the responsibilities of a model in MVVM?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I've always been a little confused as to what a "model" should or shouldn't contain - tutorials and examples often contradict each other. So far I've been playing it safe, with my models exposing nothing more than "UI stuff", e.g. properties for binding to the view, plus validation logic. But is it acceptable to have other business logic in a model?

Let's say I want to control a mechanical pump via a web service, which provides methods to turn the pump on at a given speed, and to turn it off again. My UI view might include "on" & "off" buttons, plus a textbox to set the speed. With this in mind, my model might start out like this:-

```
public class Pump
{
    public int Speed { get; set; }
}

// The real thing would implement INotifyPropertyChanged, validation, etc.
```

Is this all the model should be doing, or is it acceptable to expose the business logic for turning the pump on and off - either as methods for the view-model to call, or maybe even as ICommands that can be bound directly to the view's buttons? Or should all this be in the view-model?

**Edit**
Not sure why the downvotes, as I think this was a perfectly reasonable question. While there are many MVVM tutorials and examples on the web, they often provide conflicting advice as to what goes where, much like the answers provided below. I even ended up reading the "Advanced MVVM" e-book by WPF expert Josh Smith - the book didn't mention models whatsoever!

Anyway, I found a good resource [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx) for anyone who wants to undersatnd the structure of MVVM. While the link takes you into documentation for Microsoft's Prism framework, this particular page is all about MVVM structure, with little or no Prism-specifics. I found the page to be very informative and has at least put my mind at ease, confirming that what I've been doing over the last couple of years to be perfectly valid - that is, having models that implement INPC and validation (IDataErrorInfo), and binding these models directly to the view via VM properties (rather than duplicate model properties in the VM, as some answers below advocate).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Purpose of model is to *model* your *domain*. Entities, business logic, services - this all belongs to model. What binds it with UI is view model.

In your pump example, the `Pump` class should not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in order to utilize it in UI, because it should not be used in UI. That's the role of view model. More appropriate design would be

```
public class PumpService
{
   public void Start() { ... };
   public void Stop() { ... };
}

public class PumpControllerViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public PumpControllerViewModel(PumpService service)
    {
        StartPump = new Command(() => service.Start());
        // ...
    }
    public ICommand StartPump { get; private set; }
    public ICommand StopPump { get; private set; }
}
```

Model is in most cases almost invisible to UI. View model often exposes model properties, but seldom does so directly.  If your application would require to display *pump speed* view model would have to expose it as *observable property*.

---

*Update in response to OP question*

> (...) what if I had a more complex model with many properties, e.g. a Customer? (...) You suggest exposing each model property via an observable property on the VM - doesn't this involve a lot of duplication of properties, mapping code, etc?

Model complexity is irrelevant here and yes, such approach involes some code duplication (to some extent though).

If you keep your model simple (*[DTO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object)/[POCO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_CLR_Object)-simple*), then all you need to do is to rewrite *[POCO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_CLR_Object)-model* to *[INPC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)-view model*. Model classes would have very little code while VM would handle *to-the-view* notifications (as to its role).

Assuming that most complex models are created via factory method/builder/service (as in, not *directly*), so could be the view models. And then you can utilize automappers, serializers or whatever that is you need to ease the *duplication* process.

You will have to maintain two similar classes but this is a worthy tradeoff for a clean separation MVVM offers.

Comment: I very much agree with this Jimmy

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Perhaps the "pump" wasn't a very good example - what if I had a more complex model with many properties, e.g. a Customer? The way I've been doing things so far is to have the model implement INPC and expose it to the view via a single property in the VM, allowing the view to bind to the model's properties (e.g. "{Binding Customer.Forename}". You suggest exposing each model property via an observable property on the VM - doesn't this involve a lot of duplication of properties, mapping code, etc?

Comment: @AndrewStephens: I noticed in other comment you mention you've been using your approach *for years*. This is EOT IMO. If it works for you the way you do it, why change it? After all, it's only a **guideline** (as most stuff in software development). My team had exactly opposite experiences -- our domain (and model) grew to the point that this approach became very problematic to deal with. Later projects we went for more idiomatic MVVM and it turned out to be great to work with. YMMV.

Comment: @AndrewStephens: Here's an example of a way to avoid duplication http://jonas.follesoe.no/2009/12/23/automatic-inotifypropertychanged-using-dynamic-proxy/

Answer (score 1):

Well, actually... the "UI stuff" you mention should go in the `ViewModels`. *Some* of that stuff could be in the models also, and validation could be directly in the views (plus bindings, etc.).

I recommend reading the Prism 4.1 Developer's Guide [(chapter 5)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx), right in the first section.

Comment: This seems to be pretty much what I'm doing currently, and contradicts most of the other answers here; i.e. it says you can include validation logic and implement INPC for the purposes of binding the model to the view (and exposing the model to the view via a property on the VM).

Comment: @andrew-stephens: I understand, then, that you (we) are not doing it so bad after all... Answers are contradicting: so what? It means people have different opinions on how things should be done. Always bear in mind the ultimate goals of the pattern (i.e.: separation of concerns and loose coupling). That's practically all patterns, actually. Would you rather have a ViewModel directly expose a model object, or "proxy" (duplicate) most of its properties (and responsibilities)? The first option makes more sense to me. What are your thoughts?

Comment: I've been using my approach for a couple of years now, and found it to be satisfactory (and nice to see it's backed up by that Prism guide!). Based on the other answers here, it also seems to be acceptable to have business logic in the model, which was my original question. At the end of the day I think the key to software design is to be pragmatic.

Answer (score 0):

```
But is it acceptable to have other business logic in a model?
```

Yes it is and domain-driven advocates would encourage this design. Your business logic would be here, but not persistence logic.

```
Or should all this be in the view-model?
```

You can use your view-models as DTOs - classes with only properties to display on the view.  They should have no or very little business logic - this is a mistake that many devs make.  Your view will be bound to your view-model and the view-model will interact with your model, setting properties on it and invoking the logic it contains.

Comment: Arguably, persistance logic should be in its own model, but still in **the model** as seen by MVVM.

Comment: @Gusdor...I think persistence is an infrastructure responsibility, not a model/entity.  If you mean model as in a service or repository then, yes, I agree.

Comment: I was indeed referring to a service architecture. To me, MVVM is an application concept, not a data management scheme. Anything that isn't concerned with user input or pushing pixels is a model imo.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly in this case I would tend to use the `WebService` as the `Model`.

I think you also may have confused your `Model` with the `ViewModel`. Normally the UI specific stuff is definitely on the `ViewModel` leaving the `Model` clear to do the actual work. For example

`View` - Has a slider to set the pump speed, and a few butttons, Fast, Slow, Stop. These buttons would be bound to relevant commands on the `ViewModel` (this really helps testing too), and the slider is bound to the `Speed` property of the `ViewModel`.

```
public class ViewModel
{
  public ICommand StopCommand {get; private set;}
  // other commands

  public ViewModel()
  {
     StopCommand = new MyCommand( ()=> { Speed = 0; });
     // other commands
  }

  public int Speed
  {
    //Using webservice as model
    get { return WebService.GetSpeed(); }
    set { WebService.SetSpeed(value); }
  }
}
```

There is a really good exmaple post of this by Laurent Buyginon creator of [MVVMLight](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/), but I can't find it. Its somewhere in http://blog.galasoft.ch/posts/